A List of Worldbuilding Inspiration
In the last few days I have either promoted or heard some excellent quotes that I believe are motivational — even defining — for worldbuilding. I'm inviting all worldbuilders to contribute similar quotes to the community wiki below.

Quotes must be from published authors or notable members of the scientific community or worldbuilding community.

Quotes should be one or two sentences. Paragraph-long (or longer) quotes are inappropriate.

Contributors are invited to use the format used by the first entry.

No other answer but the Community Wiki will be permitted. All other answers will be arbitrarily deleted without moving their content to the Community Wiki.


It is my opinion that motivational quotes such as these are as valuable to the process of worldbuilding as any other process or procedure that may be described as a solution to any user's posted problem. This wiki wil be listed on the list of worldbuilding resources.
If possible, please include a citation for the quote. Thanks!

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Pity about the sentence limit, is there a way/place to suggest larger pieces? Also visual references.

As you've seen, I'm not removing quotes that simply exceed that length. I'm trying to avoid a list that's hard to read because people are posting really lengthy quotes - so it's case-by-case. Heaven help us if people start posting articles. It's supposed to be insightful and motivational, not a treatise. What visual references are you thinking about? (And how's the Douglas Adams quote about worldbuilding and/or inspirarational?)

@JBH Yeah there's a chapter from an RPG and an entire essay by Larry Niven neither are going to be small enough to include. I get a lot of inspiration from Esher. The Adams' quote is very important to sci-fi worldbuilders in particular because of how often we forget how much space there is in space.


There are only two ways to live your life. One is as though nothing is a miracle. The other is as though everything is a miracle. — Albert Einstein (attribution challenged) from The Expanded Quotable Einstein, 2000 (ISBN 0691 07021-0), Alice Calaprice Ed.


When a distinguished but elderly scientist states that something is possible, he is almost certainly right. When he states that something is impossible, he is very probably wrong. — Arthur C. Clarke


The only way of discovering the limits of the possible is to venture a little way past them into the impossible. — Arthur C. Clarke


Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic. — Arthur C. Clarke


FOR the most wild, yet most homely narrative which I am about to pen, I neither expect nor solicit belief. Mad indeed would I be to expect it, in a case where my very senses reject their own evidence. Yet, mad am I not -- and very surely do I not dream. — Edgar Allen Poe, "The Black Cat"


“Nitwit ideas are for emergencies. You use them when you've got nothing else to try. If they work, they go in the Book. Otherwise you follow the Book, which is largely a collection of nitwit ideas that worked.”
― Larry Niven, The Mote in God's Eye


I am both terrified and reassured to know that there are still wonders in the universe, that we have not yet explained everything. — G'Kar, Babylon 5


The mind that thought of light, heavy, grey, yellow, still, (and) swift also conceived of magic that would make heavy things light and able to fly, turn grey lead into yellow gold, and the still rock into a swift water.
~ JRR Tolkien


You will create parts of your world–coinage, magic, religion, sexual deviancy–that you’re especially proud of. And because you made it, you want to tell someone about it, because we are storytelling creatures... But most of your world building should not show up in your story.
~ Patrick Rothfuss


I’m not going to tell you how to start a bug-powered vehicle, I’m just going to put you inside one with somebody who knows how, and send you off on a ride.
~ Kameron Hurley


Everything in a story is worldbuilding in the same way that everything about us is worldbuilding. Every piece of technology we are carrying, every piece of clothing we’re wearing, the passports in our pockets, the contents of our wallets, that weird thing that you’ve got on that strap around your neck and what it does and why you’re carrying it and why we’re in this building, the languages on the signs… all of these things are clues as to where we come from, where we are, etc. And so it is with the fictional characters on the page.
~ Scott Lynch


As soon as you mention that maybe, say, there’s elves and dwarves in a world, people know a lot about that world. They know that there are deep, sylvan forests with skinny, tall good looking people in them. And there are mountains, with deep mines, with sturdy, bearded dwarves chipping away at them. Those worlds are already in our heads. They’re completely built. You can do new things with them, but you’re renovating. You’re not building from scratch. There is a pre-existing structure there.
~ Lev Grossman


You’re dealing with egos, you’re dealing with psychology and sociology all the aspects of human nature. And so it’s important to understand when you are doing world building, it’s important to understand the sciences. It’s important to understand both the physical sciences of how our world works, and the social sciences of how people work.
~ N.K. Jemisin


Fairy tales do not tell children the dragons exist. Children already know that dragons exist. Fairy tales tell children the dragons can be killed.
~ G. K. Chesterton


It's not speculation, it's true! Mobile phones, laptops, tablets, the internet, all were predicted and dreamed up in science fiction first. Science fiction writers speculate when they write. I don't just make random things up. I consider the world around me. I live in it. I experience it. I love it. I hate it. I worry about it. Then i imagine what's to come.
~ Nnedi Okoroafor


I'm as guilty as anyone, because I helped to herald the digital era with Jurassic Park (1993). But the danger is that it can be abused to the point where nothing is eye-popping any more. The difference between making Jaws (1975) 31 years ago and War of the Worlds (2005) is that today, anything I can imagine, I can realize on film. Then, when my mechanical shark was being repaired and I had to shoot something, I had to make the water scary. I relied on the audience's imagination, aided by where I put the camera. Today, it would be a digital shark. It would cost a hell of a lot more, but never break down. As a result, I probably would have used it four times as much, which would have made the film four times less scary. Jaws is scary because of what you don't see, not because of what you do. We need to bring the audience back into partnership with storytelling.
~Steven Spielberg


By the time of Astronomia nova, Kepler had ample mathematical evidence affirming Copernicus’s theory. But he realized something crucial and abiding about human psychology: The scientific proof was too complex, too cumbersome, too abstract to persuade even his peers, much less the scientifically illiterate public; it wasn’t data that would dismantle their celestial parochialism, but storytelling. Three centuries before the poet Muriel Rukeyser wrote that “the universe is made of stories, not of atoms,” Kepler knew that whatever the composition of the universe may be, its understanding was indeed the work of stories, not of science — that what he needed was a new rhetoric by which to illustrate, in a simple yet compelling way, that the Earth is indeed in motion. And so The Dream (Somnium) was born. — Maria Popova from How Kepler Invented Science Fiction and Defended His Mother in a Witchcraft Trial While Revolutionizing Our Understanding of the Universe, The Marginalian, adapted from Figuring (per eamdem).


“Space is big. You just won't believe how vastly, hugely, mind-bogglingly big it is. I mean, you may think it's a long way down the road to the chemist's, but that's just peanuts to space.” ― Douglas Adams, The Hitchhiker’s Guide to the Galaxy. This cannot be repeated enough in sci-fi worldbuilding.


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
